# Functor from a category to an arrow category

Tags: category-theory

I have an exercise from Maclane's book I'm stumbling with. I would like some help, thanks.

Namely, it is Exercise 7 of page 42.

> Given categories $B$, $C$, and the functor category $B^{2}$, show that
>   each functor $H : C \to B^{2}$ determines two functors $S,T: C \to B$ and
>   a natural transformation $\tau : S \to T$, and show that this
>   assignment $H \to (S,T,\tau)$ is a bijection.

Comment: You don't need any ideas to solve this exercise. Everything follows immediately from the definitions. So recall them first.

Comment: you are right, i was confused about $B^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Compose $H$ with the evaluation functors $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbf{2}} \rightrightarrows  \mathcal{B}$.

**Bigger hint:** Intuitively $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbf{2}}$ can be considered as having $\mathcal{B}$-morphisms as objects and commutative squares between such morphisms as morphisms. (To see why, think 'diagrams'.)

The evaluation functors send $\mathcal{B}$-morphism $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ to its domain (resp. codomain), and a commutative square
$$\begin{matrix}A & \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} & B \\ {\scriptsize \alpha} \downarrow\ \, & \Downarrow & \ \,\downarrow {\scriptsize \beta} \\ A' & \underset{f'}{\longrightarrow} & B\end{matrix}$$
to the left-hand (resp. right-hand) vertical morphism $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$).

You need to check that the composites of $H$ with these evaluation functors satisfy the required hypotheses, and work out how to define $\tau$.

Comment: makes sense, thank you